# AJAX request in Javascript is sent before the rest of my code

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a flask application, with a little client side javascript. I tried to send an object using AJAX form my javascript to the flask application running in the server side. However, the AJAX request is being sent beforre the rest of my JavaScript code is run (NOTE: this code is supposed to run before the AJAX request is sent). Upon searching the Internet, I learnt that this is because AJAX is asynchronous by default, but $.ajaxSetup({async: false}) did not solve my problem.

JS Code:

```
function submit(){
    var no_of_subjects = parseInt(prompt("How many classes do you teach. NOTE: if you teach the same class two sujects, then consider it as 2 classes. If you are a class teacher and you teach that class a suject, then please count that class as well. (Enter a whole number)"))
    var temp = ''
    var subjects = []
    for(var i=0;i<no_of_subjects;i++){
        temp = prompt(`${i} class. Please enter the class name and section, followed by the subject you teach. For Example: 8D Biology, or 3C LifeSkills. Please leave no other spaces other than between the class name and the subject. The possible subjects can be refered in http://127.0.0.1:5000/help`)
        subjects.push(temp)
    }
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value
    var classteacher = document.getElementById('class_teacher').value
    var teacher_id = docu.getElementById('teacher_id')
    var msg = {
        "name": name,
        "class_teacher": classteacher,
        "teacher_id": teacher_id,
        "subjects": subjects
    }
    send_message(msg)
}
function send_message(msg){
    $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
    $.post("teacher_register", msg, function(){})
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

HTML:-

```
<body>
    <div class="center"><h1 class="rainbow">Register</h1></div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fill in your credentials</legend>
        <form>
            Name : <input id="name" type="text"><br>
            Are you a class teacher? If you are, type the class of which you are the classteacher of. If you aren't, type false. : <input id= class_techer type="text"><br>
            Teacher id : <input id=teacher_id type="number"><br>
            <br><button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>
```

FLASK (python) code:-

```py
    @app.route('/teacher_register', methods=["POST"])
    def teacher_register():
        data = request.get_json()
        app.logger.debug(data)
        return data
```

Note: I get 'TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.' as the error when the code is run. By the code, I mean the Flask. This is because data has no value inside it, ie, it is None

Comment: Sorry about the coloring of the text in the HTML. Not sure what went wrong

Comment: Why do you have `preventDefault()` after everything else?

Comment: I'm looking at this on a phone so maybe I'm missing it, but what endpoint are you sending the request to?

Comment: The preventDefault is for preventing the page from reloading. The endpoint is 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/teacher_register'.

Comment: $.post("teacher_register", msg, function(){}). The "teacher_register" part

Comment: You probably need `{{ url_for('teacher_register') }}`.

Comment: No, the request is being sent alright. The problem is that the request is being sent before the rest of the JS code is run.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Same error still.

Comment: `event` is not a global object in all browsers. Pass event into the inline function or use `return false`. Best to not use inline event listeners at all and use unobtrusive ones

Comment: @charlietfl No, it still doesn't work

Comment: Not sure how you are determining sequence. Especially when event is not being prevented properly

Comment: What do you mean? Forgive me, I am a novice.

Comment: Are you sure the form isn't being submitted and reloading the page? That is likely what is happening since the code is incorrect with regard to preventing the default submit

Comment: How can I check this? Although I am pretty sure that is not the case

Comment: Then explain why you say the code isn't being run before the ajax. And make sure no errors are thrown in browser dev tools console

Comment: No errors in the console, and no, I don't have any explanation. If what you said is the case, do you have a solution?

Comment: Other than `event` not used properly it's just no clear what the actual problem is if you can't explain what is actually happening vs what is expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote does not run the $.post(..) function before the rest of the code. That is just not possible. The fact is that to override the form submission behaviour is quite a mess. Try just to alter your code so that the `<button>` is outside the form:

```
 <form>
            Name : <input id="name" type="text"><br>
            Are you a class teacher? If you are, type the class of which you are the classteacher of. If you aren't, type false. : <input id= class_techer type="text"><br>
            Teacher id : <input id=teacher_id type="number"><br>
            <br>
        </form>
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The fact is that the first button in a form is by default the 'submit' button and behaves as such by calling the declared method (GET in your case) and the default url (localhost in your case). So nothing is sent in POST and the python side then complains

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked brilliantly! Thanks to both of you! I would mention both of your names, but Stack will let me name only one user at a time.